# How to put condition in exec in a build.xml file?

Tags: ant, parameters, exec, build.xml

How to put a condition in exec in a `build.xml` file invoked from *Hudson*?

I need to use *arg* only if something happened (I send some parameters) and I need an *if* task or a condition for can solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Ant Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html) library has an if task which looks like:

```
<if>
<my condition goes here>
<then>
</then>
</if>
```

In raw Ant, you use the [condition task](http://ant.apache.org/manual//Tasks/condition.html) which looks like:

```
<condition property="condition.to.set">
   <my condition goes here>  
</condition>
```

and then a conditional target:

```
<target name="mine" if="condition.to.set">
```

I prefer Ant Contrib as it is easier to read.

Comment: It is very usefull what you said but I need to put something like this: <exec ...><if>
<my condition goes here>
<then>
</then>
</if> </exec>